# iOS Form Validation Error via if-else Condition Does Not Work Properly

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've written a simple app which validates user input (whether NULL or longer than a define length). It should return validation error messages when validation fails and otherwise, redirect to another page.

However, the app only returns the messge for the first condition (Username is Empty) for all scenarions. (Such as username is filled and password is empty, etc.)

m file:

```
- (IBAction)doLogin {

 if(uname.text==NULL) {
     UIAlertView *err1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                     initWithTitle:@"Required field!" message:@"Username is empty." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [err1 show];
 NSLog(@"%@",uname.text);         
 }

 else if(passw.text==NULL) {
     UIAlertView *err2 = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Required field!" message:@"Password is empty." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [err2 show];
 NSLog(@"%@",passw.text);
 }

 else if (uname.text.length < 6)
 {
     UIAlertView *err3 = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Invalid!" message:@"Enter a username longer than 6 chars." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [err3 show];
 NSLog(@"%@",uname.text);
 }

 else if (uname.text.length < 8)
 {
     UIAlertView *err4 = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Invalid!" message:@"Enter a password longer than 8 chars." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [err4 show];
 NSLog(@"%@",uname.text);
 }
 else {
     /*UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Thank you" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
     [alert show];*/
UIViewController* flipViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"flip" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.view addSubview:flipViewController.view];

}
```

Comment: Does it print the right NSLog?

Comment: What's "uname" ? an IBOutlet? Is uname nil or unconnected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(BOOL)isFormDataValid{

    NSString *errorMessage = nil;
    UITextField *errorField;

    if([nameTextField.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        errorMessage = @"Please enter username";
        errorField = nameTextField;
    }
    else if([[nameTextField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] length]==0)
    {
        errorMessage = @"white spaces not allowed";
        errorField = nameTextField;
    }
    else if([passwordTextField.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        errorMessage = @"Please enter password";
        errorField = passwordTextField;
    }
    else if([[passwordTextField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] length]==0)
    {
        errorMessage = @"white spaces not allowed";
        errorField = passwordTextField;
    }
if (errorMessage) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failed!" message:errorMessage delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        [errorField becomeFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }else{
        return YES;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to karthika (but using similar structure) this will provide feedback on the entire form in a single message. Perhaps a little more user friendly and certainly reduces negative user interaction.

```
-(BOOL)isFormDataValid{

    NSMutableArray *errorMessages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if([self.emailTextField.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        [errorMessages addObject:NSLocalizedString(@"Please enter email",nil)];
    }
    if([self.passwordTextField.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        [errorMessages addObject:NSLocalizedString(@"Please enter password",nil)];
    }
    if ([errorMessages count]) {
        NSString * msgs = [errorMessages componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Whoops!",nil) message:msgs delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that you do

```
else if (uname.text.length < 8)
{
    UIAlertView *err4 = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Invalid!" message:@"Enter a password longer than 8 chars." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [err4 show];
    NSLog(@"%@",uname.text);
}
```

instead of

```
else if (passw.text.length < 8)
{
    UIAlertView *err4 = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Invalid!" message:@"Enter a password longer than 8 chars." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [err4 show];
    NSLog(@"%@",passw.text);
}
```

Your code should work just fine.

Also, bear in mind that a text field's text won't be nil, it will just be an empty string (`lenght == 0`), unless you explicitly set it to `nil`.